Is MgCl2 a good polymerization inhibitor?
I've read about the formation of Liesegang pattern and decided to extend this approach to hydrogel mineralization, to see if the same result could be achieved.
Here was my idea: to prepare a PA (poly acrylamide) hydrogel that contains Mg ions, and pour NaOH solution over it so that OH- may penetrate its way downwards through the stationery phase of Mg ions.
I dissolved acrylamide, pedga1000 (cross linker), LAP (radical trigger agent) in 1g/100mL MgCl2 solution instead of water. I exposed the solution to UV lights as usual, but the results came not as solid hydrogel, but rather liquid only to be a little thicker than before. Since some ionic compounds qualify as polymerization inhibitors, I wonder if the failure of hydrogel formation could also be attributed to the presence of MgCl2?
Thank you!
